# Can I obtain discount codes using disposable email addresses?

Tags: business, european-union, fraud

A lot of online shops offer discount codes to new customers that sign up for their newsletter. While you can use an email address only once to obtain such a code I found out that using disposable email address services allows me to create such a code for every order. Is that legal? 
Obviously these discount codes are an incentive for new customers so I am not sure if this is considered a fraudulent behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the terms and conditions of the offer but *presuming* that the offer is only extended to new customers and you were an existing customer (using any email): using the code subsequent times is fraud - obtaining financial benefit by deception. It is also breach of contract.

Comment: Would this include if the user wasn't a member yet and never planned on signing up again? Like if I wanted this one time code and never wanted to use the account again